# How do I extend landing gear?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm trying to test a lander, but it keeps smashing into the ground and exploding without the landing gear extending. The process is clearly not automatic, nor is it programmable as a stage. How do I extend the landing gear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>g</kbd> will toggle the landing gear.  Additionally, 0.18 introduced a way to do this with mouse.  Next to the altimeter is a set of buttons for lights, landing gear, and brake lock.

Answer (score 4):

Besides MBraedley's answer, which covers 90+% of the use cases, you can right-click on each landing strut to toggle it individually. This can sometimes be used to right a crashed lander enough to blast off of the surface.

Landing wheels work on the same system.